# Filter data.table on condition per group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I need to incrementally update a SQL database and therefore receive the following `data.table` as input.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(Category = letters[1:4]
                  , Max.Date = rep(as.Date("2018-01-01"),4))
```

I now would like to filter the data.table in R to select all Categories, which do have a later date in my data.table `dt2`, but of course the filtering should be done on the level of the individual category, so that the dates are only compared per category and not for the whole data.table

```
dt2 <- data.table(Category = letters[1:8]
                  , Max.Date = rep(as.Date("2019-01-01"),8))
```

The desired output should select from `dt2`, where the Max.Date is larger than in `dt1`, so the desired output should be:

```
   dt.desired 
   Category   Max.Date
1:        a 2019-01-01
2:        b 2019-01-01
3:        c 2019-01-01
4:        d 2019-01-01
```

So selecting from `dt2`, where the date per category is larger than in `dt1`.

Comment: Why are `c` and `d` not in the output?

Comment: Fixed it in the edit. In my example it should return the first two rows and thus I made a mistake, when creating the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below non-equi join should work

```
dt2[ dt1, 
     .( Category, Max.Date = x.Max.Date ), 
     on = .( Category, Max.Date > Max.Date ) ][]
```

should work, resulting in:

```
#    Category   Max.Date
# 1:        a 2019-01-01
# 2:        b 2019-01-01
# 3:        c 2019-01-01
# 4:        d 2019-01-01
```